# Mouse Hover Issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to perform Mouse Hover action. I am chaining all the actions which I have to perform but I am not able to reach correct element

**My Code**

```js
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

//1st Way
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1575']//a"))).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a"))).click().build().perform();

//2nd Way
   action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1575']//a"))).perform();
   By locator = By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a");
   driver.findElement(locator).click();
```

**My HTML**

```html
<div class="flyout" style="height:100%;left:0;overflow:visible;width:100%;">
<div class="root root_menu" style="width: 100%; height: 25px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(33, 136, 201); border-top: 1px solid rgb(25, 102, 151); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);" lvl="0" arid="app1575" artype="NavBarItem" navmode="1" arwindowid="0">
<a class="btn" onclick="javascript:" style="width:213px;z-index: 1;">
<span class="navLabel root " style="width: 100%;color:#ffffff;">Quick Links</span>
</a>
<div class="flyout" style="overflow: visible; left: 0px; border-right: 1px solid rgb(25, 102, 151); display: none; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -1px; margin-left: 100%; margin-right: 0px;">
<div class="item EP lvl1 " style="height: 25px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(106, 184, 233); border-left: 1px solid rgb(106, 184, 233); border-top: medium none; border-bottom: medium none;" lvl="1" arid="app1576" artype="NavBarItem" navmode="1" arwindowid="0">
<a class="btn" onclick="javascript:CallARGSHR_58LHP_58CHP_58AppListEntryPointperfarsvrgrp_46nat_46bt_46comEPFunc(false, this);" style="z-index: 1;">
<span class="navLabel lvl1 " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Home Page</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="item EP lvl1 " style="height: 25px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(106, 184, 233); border-top: medium none; border-bottom: medium none;" lvl="1" arid="app1577" artype="NavBarItem" navmode="1" arwindowid="0">
<a class="btn" onclick="javascript:OpenAppWindow("/arsys/forms/perfarsvrgrp.nat.bt.com/AP%3AAdministration/Default+Administrator+View/?cacheid=d6be578&mode=CREATE",event);" style="z-index: 1;">
<span class="navLabel lvl1 " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Approval Administration Console</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="item EP lvl1 " style="height: 25px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(106, 184, 233); border-top: medium none; border-bottom: medium none;" lvl="1" arid="app1578" artype="NavBarItem" navmode="1" arwindowid="0">
<a class="btn" onclick="javascript:OpenAppWindow("/arsys/forms/perfarsvrgrp.nat.bt.com/NGSD%3AITSM+Configuration/New+View/?cacheid=44bb87f8&mode=CREATE",event);" style="z-index: 1;">
<span class="navLabel lvl1 " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Customer Configuration</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="item EP lvl1 " style="height: 25px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(106, 184, 233); border-top: medium none; border-bottom: medium none;" lvl="1" arid="app1579" artype="NavBarItem" navmode="1" arwindowid="0">
<a class="btn" onclick="javascript:OpenAppWindow("/arsys/forms/perfarsvrgrp.nat.bt.com/RJ%3ASQ2%3AProductCatalog/Default+Administrator+View__c/?cacheid=11b150e9",event);" style="z-index: 1;">
<span class="navLabel lvl1 " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">RJ:SQ2:ProductCatalog</span>
</a>
</div>​
```

[image]

Comment: what is the exception you are getting? just hovering on "Quick Links" results in the next level menu? or do we need to explicitly click on "right arrow" link on "Quick Links"?

Comment: No exception or error. Yes just hovering on Quick Links results in next level menu.

Comment: Are you able to open the second menu with the code? If the second menu is opening up then try with an explicit wait on the clickability of the second menu option ie in your 2nd way place the wait code before the click.

Comment: both approaches you tried are correct. If they are not working, then I suggest  click on the "Quick Links Right Arrow" link instead of hovering on it.

Comment: Explicit or Implicit wait is not working. Mouse hover is getting transferred on other links

Comment: Mouse hover on quick links keeps on blinking when this line is executed. Some times below code works (2 out of 10 Times)

       
       action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1575']//a"))).perform();
       System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a")).isDisplayed());
       
       JavascriptExecutor ex1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       ex1.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a")));
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the probabilities and finally below given code is working for me. Can anyone explain me why so?

```html
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
       act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1575']//a"))).build().perform();
                     
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       
       JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       je.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a")));
```

Thanks all for your kind Support

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code and let me know how it works.

```
//To hover on TMD link
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1575']//a"))).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a"))).build().perform();



//To click on TMD link
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1575']//a"))).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@arid='app1589']//a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of quick links"));
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("TMD")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

check for frames before going to use this